# How to fix error 'make g : command not found'?

Tags: makefile, opencl

I got following error.

```
make
g device/My_Kernel.cl -v My_Kernel.aocx
make: g: Command not found
Makefile:158: recipe for target 'My_Kernel.aocx' failed
make: [My_Kernel.aocx] Error 127 (ignored)
```

How to fix it?

Comment: According to https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options-Summary.html there is no option `g` and `-v` option outputs the version information of make. So how did you get to this command?

Comment: Not sure what is a `g` program, but `make` just informs that given program is absent on you machine. According to `.cl` and `.aocx` files extensions, the question is about opencl, so I have added this tag. The problem is *probably* related with `make` utility and Makefile you use, so I leave `makefile` tag untouched. But other tags are definitely not related to the problem: despite they have `make` substring, `cmake` and `qmake` are completely separate technologies.

Comment: @Guta: Please, add (to the question post) some **details** about what did you do when encounter this error. The questions containing only an error message without any description are very discourage.

Answer (score 0):

```
vi /tpch/dbgen/Makefile
CC = gcc
```